# PSTN to Internet

Tags: node.js, webrtc, sip, voip, telephony

I'm making a PSTN interface for some voice chat software I use, just for personal use. My current plan is this:

1. With a mobile phone, I call a number registered with Twilio and input a keypad sequence to authenticate myself.
2. My server instructs Twilio to forward a SIP call to my server.
3. I decode the SIP stream and pipe it into my (NodeJS-run) voice bot for the voice chat, and the voice chat data from the other callers are sent back to the phone.

Is there a simpler way to do this, or is this the best plan? If possible I'd like to cut SIP out of the equation since decoding that is probably a pain. The voice bot at the end is necessary, but everything else could be changed. The core requirement is that PSTN data is turned into a computer-readable stream on the Internet and that the Internet stream can be sent back to the phone.

Comment: continuing to research, maybe webrtc can help

Comment: Twilio has APIs for doing all of this.

Comment: @Brad yeah, twilio has an API for sending an SIP call to me, but what if I want the audio streamed in a different way?

Comment: What do you mean?  Can you provide a full example and use case for what you're trying to do?